# Play! validation not working

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using Play Framework 1.2.5. I have a couple of validations related to `NAme` and `Age` field. The Age validation is not working properly. Even if the age is greater than 18, I am getting the error message.

Below is the validation code in action method:

```
Error nameError = validation.required(txtName).error;
    Error ageError = validation.required(txtAge).error;
    Error minAgeError = validation.min(txtAge,18).error;

    if(nameError!=null)
        System.out.println(nameError.message("Customer Name"));

    if(ageError!=null)
        System.out.println(ageError.message("Customer Age"));

    if(minAgeError!=null)
        System.out.println(minAgeError.message("Minimun Age"));
```

Below is the messages fiule entries:

```
validation.required=%s is required
validation.min=%s cannot be lower than %2$d
```

How to make it work? No able to figure what am I misisng over here :(

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the validation logic according to the documentation.  Try this instead:

```
public static void hello(String txtName, Integer txtAge) {
     validation.required(txtName);
     validation.required(txtAge);
     validation.min(txtAge, 18);

     if(validation.hasErrors()) {
         for(Error error : validation.errors()) {
             System.out.println(error.message());
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this post, it works fine. how to make the one which I posted work? I am not able to figure out what am I missing there